# Google repository not showing on Android Studio Android SDK

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services

My application depends on Google Play Services and it gives following error.

```
Unresolved dependencies
    Error:com.google.android.gms:play-services:+
    <a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>
```

I am using Android Studio 0.6.1 with Gradle 0.11.1. I didn't update to the latest Android Studio, as it requires complete re-install.

my project dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

fails on this line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the `Google Repository` in the SDK manager?If not then install `Google Repository` form your sdk manager and than restart Android Studio.If you can't find `Google Repository` then make sure that you have upgraded to the latest SDK Tools, SDK Platform-tools, and SDK Build-tools in the Tools portion of the SDK Manager.

Comment: The problem is when I open SDK Manager, I don't see Google Repository under Extras. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to install the **Google Repository** in **Tools->SDK Manager->SDK Tools**. If **Google Repository** is not present you'll need to make sure that you've updated the **Android SDK Tools/Platform-Tools/Build-Tools** to their latest version. If updates are available the checkbox will contain a **-** click on it to change to the update icon and click apply it will update to the latest tools and you'll be able to see the **Google Repository** in Tools.
Here is the official documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update?hl=tr